# Tizen Web app Angular JS tutorial

Tags: angularjs, tizen, tizen-web-app

i am searching Angular JS tutorial in tizen site, samsung site and off course from google. but sadly i have not got any direction how to build a web app using Angular JS. i have found only 
this https://developer.tizen.org/ko/community/tip-tech/introduction-angular-2-tizen
but this is not showing any idea on tizen. 
please help.

Comment: Angular 2 or the previous version ?

Comment: any one ...i was finding angular 1, 2 ....but nothing is found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1:
Add `angular.min.js` and a js controller to your project. 
[image]

Step 2:
Add the library and controller path to the index.html

```
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/demoController.js"></script>
```

Step 3:
Add these in html

```
<html data-ng-app="myApp">
```

And

```
<body data-ng-controller="myCtrl">
```

Step 4:
Write your own code in controller,

For example,

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.CountryList = [

                          {
                              "code": "1", 
                              "Name" : "South Korea"

                          },
                          {
                              "code": "2", 
                              "Name" : "India"

                          },
                          {
                              "code": "3", 
                              "Name" : "Bangladesh"

                          },
                          {
                              "code": "4", 
                              "Name" : "Russia"

                          }

                          ];
});
```

Step 5: 
Write your own code in html,

For example,

```
<ul class="ui-listview">
    <li class="ui-li-static" data-ng-repeat="country in CountryList">
        {{country.Name}}
    </li>   
</ul>
```

View:

[image]

Comment: ** i will check this **

Comment: Hi~ have you checked... let me know

Answer (score 1):

you can try to be part of get inspiration from this project:

https://github.com/tizenteam/matrix-angular-sdk/tree/tizen